# postgres processes like mpoool using 100% cpu

Tags: cpu-load, postgresql

something I find PC very slow, and I notice that some postgres-related processes like mpool (the user is in fact postgres), are using 100% of CPU, even using all the cores, and I have to kill them. Why is that so?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is a malicious attack. If you're using postgres 9.1 or less UPDATE your postgres installation. Check your logs and you will find that scripts has been executed on your machine.

As per request, i've experienced this kind of attack on Postgres 9.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Check this post for information about this vulnerability. http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2012-3488

Easy solution is to check your log for IP information and block it in your IPTABLE. Better solution is to update your version of Postgres if your environment allows for it.

Comment: Doesn't this depend on the [Ubuntu release](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/USN-1542-1/) in use? I don't find the version of Ubuntu in use in the OP's questrion.

Comment: Perhaps, but i also dont see "mpool" as being a legitimate postgres command. I've seen this kind of script before, it's a bitcoin miner. I can provide you with more examples if you message me.

Comment: No thanks I don't need more script examples, I just thought this answer would be more accurate if you were to mention 12.04 (which it appears that this applies to.) Do you have any information that indicates that it applies to other supported versions such as 14.04, 16.04 or 16.10? That's the kind of clarification I would be interested in seeing [edit]ed into this answer. To be clear, I'm looking for accuracy, not script examples.

Comment: I can't speak for OP, but i've updated my answer about Ubuntu version

Comment: Interesting. That would indicate that [this](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/USN-1542-1/) is out of date. I found more recent information [here](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search-results?adv_search=true&cves=on&cpe_version=cpe%3a%2fa%3apostgresql%3apostgresql%3a9.1.4&startIndex=0)

Comment: As stated in your first source: "Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:
postgresql-9.1 9.1.5-0ubuntu12.04" will after my experience not fix the problem. As i had 14.04 postgresql-9.1

Comment: My apologies for any confusion you may be experiencing. I was merely attempting to bring more up to date information (in the second link) regarding the security vulnerabilities in postgres your answer references to your attention.